How do I completely wipe my hard disk from Live OS?
I have managed to go wrong with installing ubuntu and I need to start again.
I assume the reason I couldn't install ubuntu 24.04 before when i tried was because I had attempted (and failed) to download ubuntu before and had already partitioned some of the hard disk (resulting in insufficient storage). The laptop has 4GB RAM which i believe is enough to install Ubuntu 24.04.
I cannot log in or access tty so I would appreciate if someone could help me do this from bootup.

Start over by simply rebooting the LiveUSB installer.

The Ubuntu Live USB installer has an option to erase everything and install Ubuntu. Remember if you do that you will lose all the data and Windows or any other OS you may have installed in your hard disk.

Ah I see. I was using a 3rd party custom ubuntu which didn't give me that option.
